# Assign templated implementation to previously declared function

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got an `.h` file containing 2 different functions declaration:

```
#ifdef MY_HEADER
#define MY_HEADER

void a();
void b();

#endif
```

Now into `.cpp` file I want to implement those functions as different instances of another templated function:

```
#include "my_header.h"

namespace {
    template<size_t N>
    void c()
    {
        ...
    }
}

void (*a)() = c<42>;
void (*b)() = c<265>;
```

I'm getting an error message `error: 'void (* a)()' redeclared as different kind of symbol`. I've also tried `a = c<42>` and `auto a = c<42>` with no luck.

I know I can do it like this:

```
void a() {c<42>();}
void b() {c<265>();}
```

and I'm almost sure compiler will optimize this extra function call for me, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to declare this. I don't want to put `c` function itself into `.h` file either because this function is quite heavy and I don't want to have it recompiled in every source file using my header.

Comment: No, there are no better ways. *"I don't want to put c function itself into .h file either"* You don't have to put implementation in the header, just the declaration. 'Templates have to be in heades' is only true when you don't know all the types your function has to work for in advance, which is not the case here.

Comment: void (*a)(void) = c<42>

Comment: @PRDeving this does not work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to have the declarations of `a` and `b` match the definitions, so declare them as `void(*)()` variables, rather than `void()` functions.

The other answers suggesting `std::function<void()>` are ignoring that it is a very heavyweight option.

my_header.h

```
#ifdef MY_HEADER
#define MY_HEADER

extern void (*a)();
extern void (*b)();

#endif
```

my_impl.cpp

```
#include "my_header.h"

namespace {
    template<size_t N>
    void c()
    {
        ...
    }
}

void (*a)() = c<42>;
void (*b)() = c<265>;
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f6c18bb372ff9ef)

You may want to forbid `a` and `b` from being modified, and declare them as `void (* const)()`, i.e. (const pointer) to (function).

```
extern void (* const a)();
...
void (* const a)() = c<42>;
...
// a = c<53>; // error: assignment of read-only variable 'a'
```

Comment: @DenisSheremet I've also added a note about how to stop someone assigning different functions to `a` and `b`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

Header file:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER
#define MY_HEADER

#include <functional>

extern std::function<void()> a;
extern std::function<void()> b;

#endif
```

Implementation file:

```
#include "Header.h"

namespace {
    template<size_t N>
    void c() {
        ...
    }
}

std::function<void()> a = std::bind(&c<42>);
std::function<void()> b = std::bind(&c<265>);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there's a better way to declare this.

If you're looking for a more general-purpose higher wrapper for a function type, use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

In your `.h` file, declare:

```
#include <functional>
std::function<void()> a;
```

In your `.cpp` file, assign your desired function to it:

```
a = c<42>;
a();
```

Be sure about the *overhead* of using `std::function` though, it can be quite expensive for such a trivial job.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, might be a solution:

header.h

```
template<size_t N>
void c() {
  ...
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

void (*a)(void) = c<10>;

int main() {
  a();
}
```

Comment: You got me wrong, I meant `.cpp` file is some external module with `a` and `b` implementation, and `.h` file is included in some other files.